# Is it possible to create an alias or synonym for a database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to create a database alias or synonym?  What I am hoping to be able to do is have NewDatabaseName aliased as OldDatabaseName to prevent having to rewrite a ton of code.

Backstory:
I was approached by a client with a ridiculous self-induced problem.  They have a third-party application that has a SQL server back-end.  The users have been writing custom reports against this database using Visual Basic, with all database connection information hard-coded in their programs.

Recently the third party software renamed their database.  Now all the report EXE's are failing.

Oh, they dont' have a lot of the source code either.

I held back my laughter and said I would see what I could do.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No this isn't possible ([Related Feedback Item](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32893234-expand-synonym-to-other-entities-database-linked))

You could create a new database of the original name and fill that with synonyms pointing to all the objects in the renamed database though.

Comment: For anyone that finds the synonym filled database an acceptable work-around, this newer SO question has code & links to code that will simplify scripting out the synonym creation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21722066/how-to-create-an-alias-of-database-in-sql-server